# Rails4 Action Controller - undefined method 'length' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm building a messaging system from scratch for one of my projects.
Everything was working well but I just had the following error: `NoMethodError in MessagesController#index` followed by `undefined method 'length' for nil:NilClass`.
I couldn't find any answer that correspond to my case, unfortunately.

I give you `conversations_controller.rb`, `messages_controller.rb`, the models and the routes (and logs):

conversations_controller.rb

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @users = User.all
    @conversations = Conversation.all
  end

  def create
    if Conversation.between(params[:sender_id], params[:recipient_id]).present?
      @conversation = Conversation.between(params[:sender_id], params[:recipient_id]).first
    else
      @conversation = Conversation.create!(conversation_params)
    end
    redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
  end

  private

  def conversation_params
    params.permit(:sender_id, :recipient_id)
  end

end
```

messages_controller.rb :

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if @messages.length > 10
      @over_ten = true
      @messages = @messages[-10..-1]
    end
    if params[:m]
      @over_ten = false
      @messages = @conversation.messages
    end
    if @messages.last
      if @messages.last.user_id != current_user.id
        @messages.last.read = true;
      end
    end
    @message = @conversation.messages.new
  end

  def new
    @message = @conversation.messages.new
  end

  def create
    @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params)
    if @message.save
      redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
    end
  end

  private

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:body, :user_id)
  end
end
```

conversation.rb :

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, foreign_key: :sender_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, foreign_key: :recipient_id, class_name: 'User'

  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy

  validates_uniqueness_of :sender_id, scope: :recipient_id

  scope :between, -> (sender_id,recipient_id) do
    where("(conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id = ?)
            OR (conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id = ?)",
            sender_id,recipient_id, recipient_id,sender_id)
    end
end
```

message.rb :

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :body, :conversation_id, :user_id

  def message_time
    created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%y at %l:%M %p")
  end
end
```

Routes.rb :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'messages/index'

  get 'messages/new'

  get 'conversations/index'

  get 'dashboard/index'

  get 'dashboard/trips'

  get 'dashboard/messages'

  get "welcome/index"

  resources :conversations do
    resources :messages
  end

  devise_for :users

  authenticated :users do
    root to: 'dashboard#index', as: :authenticated_root
  end

  root "welcome#index"
end
```

Here, the logs:

```
Started GET "/conversations/5/messages" for ::1 at 2016-11-13 16:45:38 +1030
Processing by MessagesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"conversation_id"=>"5"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:4:in `index'


  Rendered /Users/JUSTINE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (3.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/JUSTINE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/JUSTINE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/JUSTINE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (53.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/JUSTINE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/JUSTINE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/JUSTINE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/JUSTINE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/JUSTINE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (40.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/JUSTINE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/JUSTINE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/JUSTINE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (91.6ms)
```

I hope it will be helpful for you and we will be able to find the answer :)

Cheers

Comment: You have not initialized `@messages` in the `index` action before `if @messages.length > 10` ... that's why `@messages` is nil when you try to call `length` method on it.

Answer (score 0):

The `@messages` instance variable in your `MessagesController` is not set. You need to initialize it first to something like `current_user.messages`:

```
  def index
    @messages = current_user.messages # or something like this

    if @messages.length > 10
      @over_ten = true
      # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see any error messages in ruby of the format:

```
undefined method 'method_name' for nil:NilClass
```

you are being told you are trying to call something on a nil object and so the focus of your attention should be on why is that object nil. You are also told in your log where the error occurs:

```
app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:4:in `index'
```

which is this line:

```
if @messages.length > 10
```

So @messages is nil and in this case it's nil because it hasn't actually been declared:

before the if block do something like:

```
@messages = Message.all
```

Comment: it worked but now i've got another error message which is `Couldn't find User with 'id'=0`

Comment: then you should consider posting another question as I think that's completely different issue and it's not easy to tell what the issue is without the relevant information.